# Python question using Monte carlo simulation and for loops

Tags: python, montecarlo

This is the problem:
Simulate the average of rolling two dice.
This is the code I have so far:

```
from random import seed, randint

def simulate():
    """
    Roll two dice and return their sum
    """


    dice_1 = randint(1,6)
    dice_2 = randint(1,6)
    sum = dice_1 + dice_2




### Main

seed(0) 

total = 0

# Use a for loop that runs for 1000 iterations
for trial in range(1000):
  simulate()
```

The next steps are to do this:

```
 # Call simulate() inside the loop to generate the sum
  # of two dice and add it into total
```

For now, I have already called the simulate() function, but I am a bit confused on how to add it into the total variable I have.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you want to do, but is this enough for you ?

```
from random import seed, randint

def simulate():
    """
    Roll two dice and return their sum
    """


    dice_1 = randint(1,6)
    dice_2 = randint(1,6)
    sum = dice_1 + dice_2
     # Add A return statement to get your sum after calling the function
    return sum



### Main

seed(0) 

total = 0

# Use a for loop that runs for 1000 iterations
for trial in range(1000):
  # add each time the simulation result to the total
  total = total + simulate()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).